# Angular 11 Getting the /v2/me from LinkedIn Unknown Error

Tags: angular, oauth, linkedin-api

I trying to get the r_liteprofile from LinkedIn, using the Oauth2 3-legged flow. It works flawlessly in Postman, but for some reason, it keeps returning 'Unknown Error' in Angular 11:

The code snippet:

```
params = new HttpParams()
.set('client_id', authTokenReq.clientId)
.set('redirect_uri', authTokenReq.redirectUri)
.set('client_secret', authTokenReq.clientSecret)
.set('code', authTokenReq.code)
.set('grant_type', authTokenReq.grantType);
headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
this.http.post<AccessToken>(authTokenReq.authUrl, params, {headers}).subscribe(incData => {
  this.accessToken = incData;
  console.log('incData', incData);
  console.log('access_token', this.accessToken.access_token);
  headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer'+' '+this.accessToken.access_token);
  console.log('headers', headers.getAll('Authorization'));
  this.http.get<LinkedInClient>('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)', { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken.access_token})}).subscribe(client => {
  console.log('client', client['id']);
```

Looking at the console debug from Chrome, it seems that the header is set correctly:

```
Request URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer AQWzG74CqibM05G1XiJn26y1DyPA-imcbbGB7kwFXqMUWi4t0v33d_nddqpNky4hkuUAt0rja00srjb1QIU1MzOgBtHDsci-jPS-UElbhStNcBzfFLt0FdiuydfDlIbqhrmdF8QQXFlN_2QbNpKUBGHKtDxfp-BDandIB6fCi1Uq9r8VKxUedJ1Ok--u1Lbr6rTcbXMjb0ntupidTOu9xyW9Pb5qzwOwTsj29xl9P4ymAsApq69ehAMiocRXwRhilPOLW7H2YvEbu4PElZMfw7aE3ria2Iq8CK5eRBqpKD9Sjx1ne6o23XfSfptZ6_OBFUSCATED
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
projection: (id)
```

But the pre-flight fails with a 401:

```
Request URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 185.63.144.4:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
:authority: api.linkedin.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /v2/me?projection=(id)
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en,da;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8
access-control-request-headers: authorization
access-control-request-method: GET
cache-control: no-cache
origin: http://localhost:4200
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
projection: (id)
```

Response from the preflight:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
content-length: 77
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 12:39:11 GMT
set-cookie: lidc="b=VB80:s=V:r=V:g=2759:u=1:i=1611751151:t=1611837551:v=1:sig=AQFhRnWHUE1TRiOaiG6PCqG6oXnXjSYF"; Expires=Thu, 28 Jan 2021 12:39:11 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
x-li-fabric: prod-lva1
x-li-pop: prod-efr5
x-li-proto: http/2
x-li-responseorigin: RGW
x-li-uuid: DZn48iEXXhYAduwb5yoAAA==
x-restli-gateway-error: true
```

in the debug console:

```
core.js:5967 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)", ok: false, …}
```

If run the exact same code with web security disabled like:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

It works like a charm! - does LinkedIn have problem with CORS? / does Chrome?

any ideas...?

Comment: Not sure if the Vary: Origin attribute in the response header is mandatory, but at least that seems to be missing. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more digging, I guess the easy answer to this, it that you need to get the access token and the user credentials serverside, and not from the client. I turns out that a few other flows like Twitter and Twitch-TV has the same "limitation"

I have the flow up and running with Angular 11 and Spring boot, and would be happy to share if requested